# Conformal mapping between two right-angled triangles

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, hypergeometric-function, conformal-geometry, elliptic-functions

I want to derive a conformal mapping $f\!:\!A\!\to\! B$ where $A=\{ (x,y)\ |\ x\!\in\![0,1]\  \text{ and }\  0 \leq y \leq x \}$ and $B=\{ (x,y)\ |\ x\!\in\![0,1]\  \text{ and }\  0 \leq y \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}x \}$. The regions $A$ and $B$ are the right-angled triangles with angles $\{\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{4}\}$ and $\{\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{3}\}$, respectively.

Can anyone help me derive an explicit equation for $f(x,y)$? I am vaguely familiar with the Schwartz-Christoffel mapping and the Schwartz triangle mapping, but I do not have a rigorous enough understanding of complex analysis to apply these to the above case. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: $\operatorname {sn}(z \mid 2) \operatorname {cn}(z \mid 2)$ maps the triangle with vertices $-K(-1), K(-1), i K(-1)$ to the upper half-plane, where the elliptic functions and elliptic integrals are given in the parameter notation. $z^{1/3} {_2 F_1}(1/3, 1/2; 4/3; -z)$ maps the upper half-plane to the triangle with vertices $0, z_0, e^{\pi i/3} z_0/2$, where $z_0 = \Gamma(1/6) \Gamma(4/3)/\sqrt \pi$.